# Mapping shape number to legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help in the grammar of ggplot2. I have some Data that looks like this:

```
> dput(SOData)
structure(list(Compound = c("cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd3", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd3", "cmpd3", "cmpd4", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd1", "cmpd5", 
"cmpd6", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd4", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", 
"cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd2", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd5", "cmpd7", 
"cmpd7", "cmpd4", "cmpd4", "cmpd4", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", 
"cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd7", "cmpd3", "cmpd5", "cmpd3", "cmpd6", 
"cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd3", "cmpd5", "cmpd7", "cmpd3", 
"cmpd7", "cmpd8", "cmpd8", "cmpd8", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", 
"cmpd7", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd3", "cmpd2", "cmpd3", "cmpd3", 
"cmpd4", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd1", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd1", 
"cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", 
"cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd2", "cmpd4", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd2", 
"cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd2", "cmpd1", 
"cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd1", "cmpd5", "cmpd7", "cmpd7", "cmpd4", 
"cmpd4", "cmpd4", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", 
"cmpd7", "cmpd3", "cmpd5", "cmpd3", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", 
"cmpd5", "cmpd3", "cmpd5", "cmpd7", "cmpd3", "cmpd7", "cmpd8", 
"cmpd8", "cmpd8", "cmpd6", "cmpd5", "cmpd6", "cmpd7"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Avg SS (pA)", 
"Min Peak (pA)")), value = c(274, 109, 175, 113, 86, 121, 80, 
112, 311, 110, 101, 312, 97, 419, 494, 454, 169, 80, 114, 119, 
105, 392, 207, 103, 84, 102, 100, 86, 96, 79, 339, 356, 394, 
317, 227, 158, 54, 136, 104, 107, 86, 58, 66, 84, 72, 90, 111, 
95, 134, 89, 285, 50, 69, 78, 89, 249, 90, 80, 62, 248, 72, 85, 
96, 97, 108, 85, 31, 53, 482, 551, 388, 323, 59, 74, 233, 193, 
206, 162, 79, 97, 21, 72, 170, 144, 57, 21, 68, 94, 310, 223, 
262, 191, 116, 107, 108, 116, 149, 185, 153, 76, 99, 111, 103, 
129, 119, 395, 181, 203, 293, 192, 340, 74, 130, 107, 132, 284, 
93, 72, 92, 140, 75, 57, 71, 63, 141, 154, 21, 52, 50, 106, 63, 
184, 369, 89, 223, 173, 120, 111, 191, 298, 62, 65, 72, 325, 
286, 194, 339, 128, 91, 110), Conc = c("10.0", "10.0", "10.0", 
"1.00", "1.00", "0.1", ".3", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", 
"1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", 
"1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "1.00", 
"0.1", ".3", "1.00", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", 
"10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "0.1", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", 
"0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", ".3", ".3", ".3", "10.0", "1.00", 
"1.00", "0.1", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "10.0", "0.1", "10.0", 
"1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", "0.1", 
"10.0", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", 
"10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", ".3", "10.0", "10.0", 
"1.00", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", 
"1.00", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", 
"1.00", "1.00", "0.1", ".3", "1.00", "10.0", "10.0", "10.0", 
"10.0", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "0.1", "1.00", 
"1.00", "0.1", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", ".3", ".3", ".3", 
"10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "10.0", 
"0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "10.0", "1.00", 
"0.1", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0", "1.00", "0.1", "10.0"
)), .Names = c("Compound", "variable", "value", "Conc"), row.names = c(NA, 
-150L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>)
```

My GGplot looks like so:

```
    FinalPlot = ggplot(data=SOData,aes(x=Conc,y=value,color=variable))+
geom_point(size =2,aes(x=Conc,y=value,color=variable), shape=16)+
stat_summary(aes(group=variable),fun.y=mean,geom='point',size=4,shape=9)+
scale_shape_manual('Legend',values =c(9,16))+
facet_wrap(~Compound)+
ylab('Current (pA)')+
xlab('Concentration (µM)')+
theme(text= element_text(size=14,face='bold'))+
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16,face = 'bold'))+
theme()
```

About the plot:

Each facet will be an individual compound. In each facet, I want all the values for a given condition(variable), then the mean of each variable. Right now what I have geom_point mapping the values then stat_summary doing the mean. each with a separate shape number. This works fine, but the legend is uninformative. How can I split the legend to show the point color as variable, then the shape style to be Raw or Mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to show up in the legend, you *generally* will have to add it to the `aes`. You can simply map the shape to an informative name, and map that name in your `scale_shape_manual` call to an actual shape.

```
ggplot(data=SOData,aes(x=Conc,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_point(size =2,aes(x=Conc,y=value,color=variable, shape='raw'))+
  stat_summary(aes(group=variable,shape='mean'),fun.y=mean,geom='point',size=4)+
  scale_shape_manual('Legend',values =c(mean = 9, raw = 16))+
  facet_wrap(~Compound)+
  ylab('Current (pA)')+
  xlab('Concentration (µM)')+
  theme(text= element_text(size=14,face='bold'))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16,face = 'bold'))
```

[image]

(Please note that a *minimal* example could contain a much smaller data set, with a data.frame instead of a data.table, no facets, no labels and no theme calls.)

Comment: Ah that's what I was missing. Thanks @Axeman. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you have experience in Plot_ly? When I run this in plotly the legend gets all FUBR...