# Plotly legend problems with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm having some trouble with plotly. Referenced below is a problem that was solved about the shape and legend and faceting. When i pass this ggplot to plot_ly() the legend gets all messed up. For example it says:

`````
````
1.raw
1.raw
1.raw
1.raw
2.raw
2.raw
2.raw
2.raw
2.raw
1.mean
1.mean
1.mean
1.mean
1.mean
1.mean
2.mean
2.mean
2.mean
2.mean
2.mean

````
`````

[Mapping shape number to legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365636/mapping-shape-number-to-legend/35366297#35366297)

Id just like to make the legend in the plotly look like the legend in ggplot, except with the added bonus of interactivity of the traces.

Just for easiness here is the code:

```
FinalPlot = ggplot(data=SOData,aes(x=Conc,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_point(size =2, aes(shape='raw'))+
  stat_summary(aes(group=variable,shape='mean'),fun.y=mean,geom='point',size=4)+
  scale_shape_manual('Legend',values =c(mean = 9, raw = 16))+
  facet_wrap(~Compound)+
  ylab('Current (pA)')+
  xlab('Concentration (µM)')+
  theme(text= element_text(size=14,face='bold'))+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16,face = 'bold'))

plot_ly(FinalPlot)
```

Data can be found in the link above.

Thanks!

Comment: it does look it's possible; if you look at the last example (https://plot.ly/ggplot2/facet_grid/) the legend is also lost.

Comment: Yeah I noticed they didn't have the legend there. Maybe I'll reach out to Plotly and see what they say

Comment: I would like to know as well. Plotly and ggplot2 does always work perfectly together :-)

Comment: Im having similiar issues, any updates here?